# I'm not sure how to use lodash orderBy

Tags: javascript, lodash

My program is currently supposed to take the HTML input, put it into an object array, sort it using orderBy, then output it to the p2 textContent. I tested all of the aspects of this program before adding orderBy, and then the program stopped working.

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
var enterName = document.getElementById("name");
var enterRating = document.getElementById("rating");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var players = [];

button.addEventListener("click", addPlayer);

function addPlayer() {
  p1.innerText += enterName.value + " - " + enterRating.value + " " + "| ";
  players.push({ player: enterName.value, rating: enterRating.value });

  var sortedPlayers = _.orderBy(players, [rating, player], [desc, desc]);

  console.log(players);
  console.log(sortedPlayers);
  p2.innerText = "";
  for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    p2.innerText += players[i].player + " - " + players[i].rating + " | ";
  }
}
```

p1 exists and is used for testing purposes, just to make sure that my browser isn't lagging. After I added the orderBy, neither array logged to the console. Before, the players array logged with every run of the `addPlayer()` function.

I'm using codepen to write this program, and I am pretty sure lodash is installed if that is relevant.

Comment: `[rating, player], [desc, desc]` should be arrays of strings.

Comment: My Chromebook is about to die. I will respond to any comments or answers once I get it to a charger. (I am out of my house currently)

Comment: As a supplement: use `var sortedPlayers = _.orderBy(players, ['rating', 'player'], ['desc', 'desc']);`. Please further attach a complete example - fill the input directly in the code and define the expected behavior.